# What kind of animation is used for this?

Tags: android, android-animation

Anyone familiar with the emulator will know that during the loading phase the 'screen' of the AVD shows the word 'android' as in the image below...

[image]

The highlight (on the letters DRO in the image) 'scans' from left to right to act as an indeterminate progress indicator.

I don't do much graphics work so I'm not familiar with different animation techniques. Is that type of animation a common one and if so, what is it's name?

I'd like to implement something similar in my main activity's title bar. When opened, it would do a single highlight 'scan' of the activity name. No real purpose other than to add a bit of 'glitz' to the UX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is most likely a bitmap animation (sprite animation) or two images where one is the effect layer put on top.

A sprite animation is simply put a prerendered imageset where the frames are just switched at a specified rate.

The other alternative is a partly transparent mask that is animated over the background image from left to right.

To illustrate the second point:

1. First you have the background image:

[image: background]

2. Then you have the mask. Note that white and transparent on white doesn't show that well. Here's a link to the image as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6QsK.png

[image: mask]

3. When combined with an offset of the mask you get something like

[image: combined]

So you simply draw the mask over the background image and alpha blending will take care of the rest.
The simplest way is probably to animate an imageview from a position that is 0-mask.width to a position that is background.width+mask.width.

If you want the mask to be more dynamic you will probably want to generate and render it for example in a custom view where you draw in `onDraw` to a canvas.
You could make the effect a bit cooler if you combine it with a rotation using an AnimationSet (or Animator depending on Android target).

Comment: +1 Thank you for your detailed answer - you have given me a good starting point. I downloaded your 'highlight' mask and can see it properly using gimp. I'll put together a test Activity and try some things.

Comment: I think I've worked out what needs to be done now and have made a good start. Thanks again.